# Angular 9 GET api Http failure response 404 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, angular9

I'm calling REST API from UI, but I'm getting below error

Error Code: 404
Message: Http failure response for https://localhost:5001/api/SampleDataSource/GetDetailsById?id=101 404 OK

```
query(queryStringParameters?: any): Observable < object > {
      private headers = new HttpHeaders(); 

     this.headers = this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
      this.headers = this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      this.headers = this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      this.headers = this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

     return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '?' + queryStringParameters, { headers: this.headers }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

c# Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
        public class SampleDataSourceController : Controller
        {
         [HttpGet("GetDetailsById")]
                public IActionResult GetDetailsById([FromQuery] string id)
                {

                    return Ok(null);
                }
    }
```

General:

```
Request URL: https://localhost:5001/api/SampleDataSource/GetDetails?id=101
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:5001
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Reponse Headers:

access-control-allow-origin: *

```
connection: keep-alive
content-length: 174
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 05 Jun 2020 15:02:42 GMT
server: Kestrel
status: 404
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-powered-by: Express
```

Request Headers:

```
:authority: localhost:5001
:method: GET
:path: /api/SampleDataSource/GetDetails?id=101
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,te;q=0.7
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: application/json
cookie: ai_user=d3TQ|2020-06-04T15:35:45.072Z; ai_session=gU3qi|1591367714431|1591367843063.445
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://localhost:5001/
request-id: |ed257af3e5b34db4be330d4be3b41449.ac4bec56ee484ece
sec-ch-ua: "\\Not;A\"Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="85", "Chromium";v="85"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4158.4 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 2):

404 - is standard error, that requested resource not found. Check your api URL, looks like you url is wrong (may be typo?). Also, to verify url check Network tab in Chrome to see real URL
[image]

Comment: No , URL is correct. I've verified in Network tab and in C# controller. I'm thinking some how HttpHeaders are creating issue.

Comment: Check also wich method you use in controller and angular. POST/GET/other. On both sifrs they should be same.

Comment: I've edited my question. I kept break point also. It never hitting the break point in controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can add queryStringParameters in HttpParams like this

```
    query(queryStringParameters?: any): Observable < object > {
        private headers = new HttpHeaders(); 

        this.headers = this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        this.headers = this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers = this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        this.headers = this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
        const httpParams = new HttpParams().set('page', queryStringParameters.page).set('sort', queryStringParameters.sort);

         return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL{ headers: this.headers, params: httpParams }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
     }
```

Comment: No Luck, same error.  I've created one more GET event without Params. But, I'm getting same error.

Comment: add "/" at last in  your API url